# Search bar with 2 foreign key in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

In my search bar which is on the folder `book.index.blade.php` I would like to do a search on the `name` of my table `authors` or the field `code` of my table `bookcases`.

[image]

So far, I know to do a search on the field `name` of my table `authors`.
My problem is how to do also the request with the field `code` of my table `bookcases` ? I don't know the syntax... 
I am novice.

```
public function index(Request $req) 
{
    if ($req->search == "") {
          $books = Book::paginate(5);
          return view('admin.books.index', compact('books'));

    } else {

            $validated = $req->validate([
                'search' => 'alpha', 
            ]);

   $books = Book::whereHas('authors', function($query) use($req) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $req->search . '%');
        })->paginate(5);
  return view('admin.books.index', compact('books'));
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for SQL or Laravel answer?

Comment: @jarlh: Laravel , I don't know the synthax in fact...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append more *whereHas* conditions to the search, like so:

```
$books = Book::whereHas('authors', function($query) use($req) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $req->search . '%');
    })->whereHas('bookcases', function($query) {
        $query->where('code', 'like', '%' . $req->search . '%');
    })->paginate(5);
```

If you'd like to search in the authors **or** in the bookcases, you can change the second *whereHas* to *orWhereHas*.

**Obs**: I'd recommend you to learn a little bit more about Laravel's eloquent way of relating objects. It has a learning curve but it sure helps out in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [Search on Eloquent Relationships](https://pineco.de/search-eloquent-relationships)

Otherwise you can use a join to do this as well:

```
Book::join('authors', 'books.fk_author', 'authors.id')
    ->join('bookcases', 'books.fk_bookcase', 'bookcases.id')
    ->where('authors.name', 'LIKE', '%'. $req->search . '%')
    ->select('authors.name', 'table.other_column', 'table.another_column')
    ->paginate(5);
```

Tip for adding orWhere if you have multiple searches use something like this its more reliable:

```
->where(function ($query) {

    $query->orwhere('users.name', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%')
        ->orWhere('users.id', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
restructuring books table to:
id
title
gender
author_id
bookcases_id


public function index(Request $req) 
{
   $s = $req->input('data');
    $data['search']=DB::table('books')
    ->leftjoin('authors', 'books.author_id', '=', 'authors.id')
    ->leftjoin('bookcases', 'books.bookcases_id', '=', 'bookcases.id')
    ->where('books.id','=',$s)
    -orWhere('bookcases.id','=',$s)

    return view('admin.books.index', $data);

}
```

hope this helps. this is query builder. just import `use DB;`